# Find the determinant of a sum of idempotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, diagonalization, idempotents

> Let $A, B \in \mathcal{M}_n (\mathbb{R})$ such that $A^2 = A$ and $B^2 = B$. If $\det(2A + B)=0$, prove that $$\det(A + 2B) = 0$$

---

My attempt:

I know that both matrices are diagonalizable and their all of their eignvalues are either $0$ or $1$. I can assume that one of them, lets say $A$ is in its diagonalized form but this doesn't help very much as long as I don't have any information about $B$'s form. I was also thinking about multiplying the matrix $2A+B$ with another matrix to use that the matrices are idempotent and simplify things, but I haven't managed to get anything too useful.

Another good idea of mine is to take a nontrivial vector $v$ such that
$(2A+B)\cdot v=0$ and then $2A\cdot v+B\cdot v=0$ and now my idea was to multiply the left hand side by $ \overline{{v^t}}$ and use that $A^2=A$ and $B^2=B$ but I don't know that $A=A^t$ so I can't form a scalar product of 2 vectors.

Comment: Since no one has answered yet, there is no need to append an `Edit`.  Just refine the question.  You won't be orphaning any answer.

Comment: Solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1465058p8478822

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is a valid solution in "Art of Problem Solving".

Comment: @DietrichBurde Is the AoPS solution the only possible one?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I do not think that the presence of a solution on some external site is a good reason to close the question (unless you take it as an indicator did not “show any research effort”).

Comment: @MartinR I just was not sure whether it should stay open and someone just copies the solution as an answer at this site. A copy paste is probably not what we want (quality requirements). Anyway, the question is answered, and I don't mind if it stays open here.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Are you concerned about the quality of the question or of an answer? If the question is fine (which seems to be the case here, but this is not my area of expertise) then I do not see a problem with posting an answer which is inspired by AoPS (with proper attribution). I have done that before.

Comment: @MartinR No, I am not concerned about the quality of the question or of the answer. It feels more like a plagiarism. But feel free to write a good answer (maybe using a different idea somewhere), then I will upvote it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I do not plan to answer this question. I was just wondering if “There is a valid solution in Art of Problem Solving” is a valid reason to *close* a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a straightforward solution.

$A$ and $B$ are projections.

Let $\text{Im}(A)=S,\text{Ker}(A)=T,\text{Im}(B)=U,\text{Ker}(B)=V$.

So you can interpret the conditions in the problem as follows:

$\mathbb{R}^n=S\oplus T=U\oplus V$

There exist $s\in S, t\in T, u\in U, v\in V$ such that $s+t=u+v\neq0$ and $2s+u=0$.

$\\$

It follows that $u=-2s$ and $v=3s+t$.

Now, $as+bt=(a-3b)s+(3bs+bt)$, where $(a-3b)s\in U$ and $3bs+bt\in V$.

So look for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $A(as+bt)+2B(as+bt)=as+2(a-3b)s=(3a-3b)s=0$.

We can set $a,b=1$. We have already stated that $s+t\neq0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which I think is more natural, although it is somewhat longer than those on AoPS.

Suppose $Ax=kBx$ for some scalar $k\notin\{0,1\}$ and some nonzero vector $x$ (in your case $k=-\frac12$). Then $Ax$ and $Bx$ are either both zero or both nonzero. In the former case, clearly any linear combination of $A$ and $B$ are singular.

Suppose $Ax$ and $Bx$ are nonzero. If $x$ and $Ax$ are linearly dependent, we must have $Ax=x$. But then $Bx=\frac1kAx=\frac1kx$, which is a contradiction to the assumption that $B$ is idempotent. Therefore $x$ and $Ax$ are linearly independent. It follows that $V=\operatorname{span}\{x,Ax\}$ is a two-dimensional invariant subspace of both $A$ and $B$ (and this is the key observation in my proof). The matrix representations of the restrictions of $A$ and $B$ on $V$ with respect to the ordered basis $\{x,Ax\}$ are respectively
$$
\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&1}\text{ and }\pmatrix{0&0\\ \frac1k&1}.
$$
It is now evident that every linear combination of $A$ and $B$ is singular. Using these matrix representations, one can also easily find a non-trivial solution to $(\lambda A+\mu B)v=0$. For instance, we have
$$
(B-kA)\big[(k+1)Ax-kx\big]=0.
$$